# random sampling with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, montecarlo

I'm relatively new to pandas (and python... and programming) and I'm trying to do a Montecarlo simulation, but I have not being able to find a solution that takes a reasonable amount of time

The data is stored in a data frame called "YTDSales" which has sales per day, per product

```
Date          Product_A     Product_B     Product_C     Product_D     ...   Product_XX
01/01/2014         1000           300            70         34500     ...          780   
02/01/2014          400           400            70            20     ...           10   
03/01/2014         1110           400          1170            60     ...           50   
04/01/2014           20           320             0         71300     ...           10   
       ...
15/10/2014         1000           300            70         34500     ...         5000
```

and what I want to do is to simulate different scenarios, using for the rest of the year (from October 15 to Year End) the historical distribution that each product had. For example with the data presented I will like to fill the rest of the year with sales between 20 and 1100.

What I've done is the following

```
# creates range of "future dates"
last_historical = YTDSales.index.max()
year_end = dt.datetime(2014,12,30)
DatesEOY = pd.date_range(start=last_historical,end=year_end).shift(1)

# function that obtains a random sales number per product, between max and min
f = lambda x:np.random.randint(x.min(),x.max())

# create all the "future" dates and fill it with the output of f
for i in DatesEOY:
    YTDSales.loc[i]=YTDSales.apply(f)
```

The solution works, but takes about 3 seconds, which is a lot if I plan to 1,000 iterations... Is there a way not to iterate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `size` option for `np.random.randint` to get a sample of the needed size all at once.
One approach that I would consider is briefly as follows.

1. Allocate the space you'll need into a new array that will have index values from DatesEOY, columns from the original DataFrame, and all NaN values. Then concatenate onto the original data.
2. Now that you know the length of each random sample you'll need, use the extra `size` keyword in `numpy.random.randint` to sample all at once, per column, instead of looping.
3. Overwrite the data with this batch sampling.

Here's what this could look like:

```
new_df = pandas.DataFrame(index=DatesEOY, columns=YTDSales.columns)

num_to_sample = len(new_df)

f = lambda x: np.random.randint(x[1].min(), x[1].max(), num_to_sample)

output = pandas.concat([YTDSales, new_df], axis=0)

output[len(YTDSales):] = np.asarray(map(f, YTDSales.iteritems())).T
```

Along the way, I choose to make a totally new DataFrame, by concatenating the old one with the new "placeholder" one. This could obviously be inefficient for very large data.

Another way to approach is [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) as you've done in your for-loop solution.

I did not play around with that approach long enough to figure out how to "enlarge" batches of indexes all at once. But, if you figure that out, you can just "enlarge" the original data frame with all NaN values (at index values from `DatesEOY`), and then apply the function about to `YTDSales` instead of bringing `output` into it at all.